# Core plot legend doesn't show up every time

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

i have a problem regarding a pie chart's legend in core plot framework (for iOS).
I'm adding two plots to the graph (CPTXYGraph) object:

```
CPTPieChart *piePlot = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
piePlot.dataSource = self;
piePlot.pieRadius = 60.0;
piePlot.identifier = @"After";
piePlot.startAngle = M_PI_4;
piePlot.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
piePlot.centerAnchor = CGPointMake(0.7, 0.67);
piePlot.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
piePlot.delegate = self;
[pieChart addPlot:piePlot];
[piePlot release];

CPTPieChart *piePlotSecond = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
piePlotSecond.dataSource = self;
piePlotSecond.pieRadius = 60.0;
piePlotSecond.identifier = @"Before";
piePlotSecond.startAngle = M_PI_4;
piePlotSecond.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
piePlotSecond.centerAnchor = CGPointMake(0.27, 0.67);
piePlotSecond.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
piePlotSecond.delegate = self;
[pieChart addPlot:piePlotSecond];
[piePlotSecond release];
```

This works fine so far, and here comes the legend:

```
CPTMutableTextStyle *legendTextStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
legendTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;
legendTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[pieChart plotAtIndex:0]]];
theLegend.numberOfColumns = 2;
theLegend.textStyle = legendTextStyle;
theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];
theLegend.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
theLegend.cornerRadius = 5.0;

pieChart.legend = theLegend;

pieChart.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorRight;
pieChart.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(-33.0, -90.0);
```

This simply doesn't show up every time. Meaning: on the simulator it's almost perfectly fine, but on the device it only appears every 3rd or 4th time. Also, it gives me the following warning message:

> ..-[<< bounds: {{0, 0}, {8.58993e+09, 125}}> for plots (
>       "< bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 367}}>"
>   )> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (8589934592.000000, 125.000000)

The graph hosting view is in a uiscrollview object along with another chart (a bar chart), which is working perfectly. Also, i didn't notice this problem with only one pie chart (but that doesn't mean it didn't exist). But unfortunately i need two pie charts in the same view, close to each other. And with one legend only, because they have the same fields, just with different values.

Am i doing something wrong, or this is some kind of bug maybe? Is there a way to fix it? Sadly replacing the legend with some image isn't a solution, because the names are dynamic.

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention: it's 0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled myself a new version from the available source code of core plot, and it seems the problem has gone away.

I'm playing with the chart for a good 15 minutes now, and it's working.

I guess it was a bug in the 0.4 release.